# Is Frame Layout is necessary in navigation drawer in android?

Tags: android

I've been searching for how to implement Navigation Drawer to my android application. All the tutorial i saw were using Frame Layout in main activity. Is it necessary to use Frame Layout in Navigation Drawer?

Comment: why not try another layout, and see what happens?

Comment: The answer is yes. You must use `FrameLayout` to place `Fragment`s. And `RelativeLayout` is used to place your `MainActivity`. Because of `Fragment` has different lifecycle with `Activity`, so you must replace and begin transaction with it.

Comment: R.id.ic_drawer is showing error in ActionBarToogle?